# Pycharm: What do these auto-complete icons mean?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: :]

So, as you can see, there is a yellow 'v' accompanying every autocomplete suggestion. What do these icons mean? Is it simply an indication that it is an auto-complete menu?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that particular auto-complete suggestion refers to a variable, and not a class, function, ...

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html